# How can I use enum to Binding data in SwiftUI?

Tags: enums, swiftui

I'm trying to bind to an enum instance's rawValue

```swift
enum Brand: Int, CaseIterable, Codable {
    case toyota = 0
    case mazda
    case suzuki
}

struct Car {
    var brand: Brand
}

struct CarView: View { 

    @Binding car: Car  
 
    var body: some View {
        SomeView(selectionInt: $car.brand)
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Binding' to expected argument
> type 'Binding'.

If've tried using $car.brand.rawValue instead (in SomeView's parameters) but then I get this error:

> Cannot assign to property: 'rawValue' is immutable.

How can i bind my View to the model instance's rawValue?

Comment: Make you Car strict an ObservableObject class and make brand Published. You will save yourself all the headache of a workaround. Binding is a two-way connection it needs a parent that can store and can be Observed.

Comment: @lorem-ipsum To make the Car struct an ObservableObject I'd have to convert it to a class. In my actual code I'm not dealing with cars at all and the model i'm representing by a car in this example is actually a struct that conforms to Codable and which is a child of another Codable struct or two. To stick with the car analogy, when I'm accessing the  car's brand, it's actually a member of the Vehicle model... vehicle.groundVehicle.car.brand. The "Vehicle" gets decoded from an XML file and I'm afraid I might mess up everything I've set up so far if I stray too far from my current setup.

Comment: No problem I figure I would suggest it. You can always conform to `Codable` manually with a `class`. The workaround in the answer just seems a lot of work when you are likely dealing with many `var` in your `struct` the workaround below is just creating a new `Car` every time. You might as well just pass the whole `Car` with `@State` as the parent and `@Binding` as the child and save yourself the potential for errors (caused by multiple variables). What happens with the rest of the existing variables? like a new license plate number? You don't have the original information handy in the child

Comment: Yeah. I feel I need a new approach. Instead of trying to bind the selectionInt to the Car.brand, I could perhaps keep it as a simple @State var selectionInt: Int and then set the car instance's brand with a function call? Through some kind of onChange call tied to the SomeView() Pager?

Comment: You can only bind to a single variable effectively if you use `@State` (In a `View`) or `@Published` in a `ObservableObject` `class`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a `brandProxy` to maintain the integrity of the other `Car` variables

```
import SwiftUI
enum Brand: Int, CaseIterable, Codable {
    case toyota = 0
    case mazda
    case suzuki
    case unknown
    
    func description() -> String {
        var result = "unknown"
        switch self {
        case .toyota:
            result = "toyota"
        case .mazda:
            result = "mazda"
        case .suzuki:
            result = "suzuki"
        case .unknown:
            result = "unknown"
        }
        return result
    }
}
struct CarView: View {
    //This makes it mutable
    @State var car: Car
    var brandProxy: Binding<Int> {
        Binding<Int>(
            get: {
                car.brand.rawValue
            },
            set: {
                car.brand = Brand(rawValue: $0) ?? Brand.unknown
            }
        )
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(car.brand.description())
            SomeView(selectedIndex: brandProxy)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers. The first option looks very similar to the code I currently have but I'm not using a Picker. I'm using a third party Pager which only takes an Int for it's 'selection', hence my attempt to retrieve the brand's rawValue.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of this earlier. use a proxy. I updated the code. This won't replace your entire `Car`

Comment: Perfect. This was the simple solution I was hoping for. Cheers!

Comment: @Ribena: what was basically wrong with my code or what is new with this answer?!

Comment: @swiftPunk There was nothing wrong with your answer per se. It was helpful! This one was just easier for me to wrap my head around, with no changes to any code beyond declaring a new variable. Because my code doesn't actually deal with cars or car models at all but is more complex, lorem ipsum 's solution was a better fit for me to keep things simple. Feeding in the Binding.init(get: { () etc. line (from your solution) into SomeView's parameters was a little scary to me. No doubt others coming to this question will prefer your answer though and upvote that instead!

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of binding you need a custom Binding to help SwiftUI to Bind data!

**Info: You can not change rawValue of enum because they are immutable!**
and also try of changing them in way of Binding would not help you, they are immutable! **you can get them not set them!**

*So with that info you can know why SwiftUI does not want Bind it at fist place! because if SwiftUI make that Binding possible that would be a BIG violation of enum rawValues! then we will try use Binding power in this way that we change the Int of car not Enum. see the code for example.*

---

[image]

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedCar: Car = Car(brand: Brand.suzuki)
    
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            
            Picker("", selection: $selectedCar.brand) {
                
                ForEach(Brand.allCases, id: \.self) { car in
                    
                    Text(car.description)
                    
                }
                
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
        }
        .padding()

        
        CarView(selectionInt: Binding.init(get: { () -> Int in return selectedCar.brand.rawValue },
                                           set: { newValue in
                                            
                                            if let unwrappedBrand = Brand(rawValue: newValue) { selectedCar = Car(brand: unwrappedBrand) } }) )
        
    }
}
```

---

```
struct CarView: View {
    
    @Binding var selectionInt: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("selected Int: " + selectionInt.description)
            .padding()
        
        let selectedCar = (Brand(rawValue: selectionInt)?.description ?? "unknown")
        
        Text( "selected car: " + selectedCar)
            .padding()
        
        
        VStack(spacing: 20.0) {
            
            Button("select toyota") { selectionInt = 0 }
            Button("select mazda") { selectionInt = 1 }
            Button("select suzuki") { selectionInt = 2 }
            
        }
        .font(Font.body.weight(Font.Weight.bold))
        
    }
}
```

---

```
enum Brand: Int, CaseIterable, Codable, CustomStringConvertible {
    
    case toyota = 0
    case mazda = 1
    case suzuki = 2
    
    var description: String {
        
        switch self {
        case .toyota: return "toyota"
        case .mazda: return "mazda"
        case .suzuki: return "suzuki"
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct Car {
    var brand: Brand
}
```

Comment: Trying this out with my code and it's working almost as I expect it. SomeView correctly displays the relevant Image based on the car's brand. But SomeView is actually some kind of selector/pager. It seems like it's getting but not setting the brand when i page to another brand. So I how would I have it so that it's a two-way binding.

Comment: @Ribena: So the new issue is nothing to do with your question you asked, as we know the question is about **Binding to an enum's rawValue in SwiftUI** and I think I explained it with working example. the new issue that you are asking could be about your code debugging, and I think it is better asked in separate question. with the code and View make that issue happen. thank you.

Comment: Fair enough. I should have framed the initial question in terms of what I was trying to achieve. Thanks for the updated answer.

Comment: @Ribena: I just updated that Custom Binding in this way that you can change the car as well and a little clean up in codes.

Comment: Cheers. Your answer works but ultimately I'm changing the accepted answer to be lorem ipsum's, as it better answers the spirit of my question. I will try to be clearer next time though, as I agree that I didn't quite ask the same thing in the question title and body.

Comment: @Ribena: But i am interested for leaning what is new in new Answer? what I am missing?

Comment: It could be that it's essentially the same answer... You seem to be implying that? I am nowhere near yours or lorem ipsum's level so I wouldn't know. I do know that I clearly understood one answer and not so much yours, which had me feeding functions straight into my view as parameters. I don't want to offend anyone and I appreciate both answers! - so I can revert the accepted answer back to yours if both are actually the exact same answer?

Comment: TLDR; your bid to be helpful by adding a ContentView, a picker and other code I didn't use in my example actually confused my poor little brain!

Answer (score 1):

Where appropriate, I like defining my `enums` to be `String`-based. This is especially useful when the data will be saved to Firebase. When I look at the database, I see the actual values instead of 0s, 1s and 2s that I then have to remember/lookup what they actually stand for.

```
enum Brand: String, CaseIterable, Codable {
    case toyota = "Toyota"
    case mazda = "Mazda"
    case suzuki = "Suzuki"
}

struct Car {
    var brand: Brand
}

struct CarView: View { 
    @State car: Car  
 
    var body: some View {
        SomeView(with: $car.brand)
    }
}

struct SomeView: some View {
    @Binding var brand: Brand
    ...
}
```

`@State` makes it mutable in the original View. `@Binding` allows another view to make changes and propagate them back to the original view. Going back to the OP's original question, it seems that where you say `@Binding` should have been `@State` and you should have a `@Binding` definition in the SomeView definition. So, you were almost there.